# How do I make space between <nav> and <section>

Tags: html, css

I'm just looking to get a Space between the `<nav>` tag and the `<section>` tag. At the minute in the browser they are flush to each other. I  want to have a space between them, but i'm not sure how.

Here is my simple code -

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>About Me</title>
    <srcipt></srcipt>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<header>

<h1>About me</h1>

</header>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href="index.hmtl">Who I Am</a> -
            <a href="from.hmtl">Where I am From</a> -
            <a href="study.hmtl">What I am Studying</a> -
            <a href="more.html">Race the Flux</a> -
            <a href="gear.html">My Gear</a>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section>
        <div id="first">
        <p>
        Nam egestas, nibh non efficitur luctus, nisi eros
        </p>

        <p>
        Nam egestas, nibh non efficitur luctus, nisi eros

        </p>
        <img src="images/Me.jpg">

        <p> 
        Nam egestas, nibh non efficitur luctus, nisi eros
       </p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer><a href="from.html">Next Page</a></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body: lang(en) {
    margin-top: 2em;
}

body {

    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 6em 3% 19em 3%;
    background: #F8F8F8  ;
    color: black;
    font: Arial;
    position: relative;

}

body{

    display: block;
}


#first {

    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    width: 550px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 .3em 1em #000;
}

nav {

    box-shadow: 0 .1em 1em #000;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: white;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black

}

a {
    color: black;
}

img {

    width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid black
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

footer {

    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    margin: 10;
    padding: 10;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add some margin to the bottom of the `<nav>` (or to the top of `<section>`):

```
nav {
    box-shadow: 0 .1em 1em #000;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px; /* this line */
    background-color: white;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsbin.com/gaqunaraca/edit?css,output)

Also you can shorten your different `margin` definitions by:

```
margin: 0 auto 30px;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this, depending on how you want it to look, the speed, and the function of this.

Just create a div with this style in-between the two:

```
#spacer {height:50px;}
```

Or put a blank png image in between.

Or just give the nav a bottom margin, or the section a top margin.